# Avoid repeating session and access right checks in codeigniter 3 controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have implemented a simple role check code with the help of helpers using sessions in my codeigniter 3 application.

Access Helper: Defines a function named as access_right which checks if the logged in user has access right to visit a specific module or not and correspondingly returns true or false.

In addition to it, I also have two versions of navigation bars one for admin user and for non admin users.

In controller i have added following code to perform the check for both i.e. which navigation to load and if the logged in user has access or not to module:

```
if($this->session->userdata('user-type') === 'admin')
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/sub_header_admin');
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/sub_header');
    }

    if(access_right('client_information'))
    {
        $this->load->view('pages/clientview/client_page');
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/restricted_access');
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Problem is I need to repeat this much of code in each and every method inside a controller.

`access_right('client_information')`, of-course instead of client_information i check for different value like 'operator_information' depending on which controller is loaded.

How can i avoid this repetition of code ?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you avoided repeating code for checking 'client_information' access rights - create a function to do that.